# Value-At-Risk (VaR) curve with Copula-GARCH model (R)

Tags: r, var

I'm trying to creave a VaR curve with the Copula-GARCH model in R.
Here's what I have:

```
library("fGarch")
library("quantmod")
library(ghyp)
library(copula)
```

Getting stock prices for Boeing & Airbus and calculating yields:

```
getSymbols("BA", from="2014-01-01", to="2016-10-19")
p<-as.numeric(Ad(BA))
l<-length(p)
y<-p[2:l]/p[1:(l-1)]-1
getSymbols("AIR",from="2014-01-01", to="2016-10-19")
p1<-as.numeric(Ad(AIR))
y1<-diff(p1)/head(p1,-1)
```

Creating an optimal portfolio:

```
gammas <- seq(0,1,0.001)
var <- var(y)*gammas^2 + var(y1)*(1-gammas)^2 + 2*cov(y, y1)*gammas*(1-gammas)
optimal <- (var(y1) - cov(y, y1))/(var(y) + var(y1) - 2*cov(y, y1))
optimal
prt<-optimal*y+(1-optimal)*y1
y2<-cbind(y,y1)
head(y2)
```

2D distribution of yields:

```
cdf<-pobs(y2)
plot(cdf)
```

Initializing copula:

```
t.cop<-tCopula(dim=2, param=0.5, df=2, df.fixed=TRUE)
fit<-fitCopula(data=cdf, copula=t.cop)
summary(fit)
```

Monte-Carlo & VaR:

```
N0<-10000
points_cop<-rCopula(copula=fit@copula, N0)
plot(points_cop, cex=0.2)
y_cop<-quantile(y, points_cop)
y1_cop<-quantile(y1, points_cop)
prt_y2<-optimal*y_cop+(1-optimal)*y1_cop
quantile(prt_y2, 0.05)
```

The problem is about obtaining a VaR curve (here's splitting the sample into a test and examinating sample):

```
N1<-15000
test1<-prt_y2[(N1+1):length(prt_y2)]
VaR1<-rep(0,length(test1))
for(i in (N1+1):length(prt_y2))
{train1<-prt_y2[(i-N1):(i-1)]
...............
}
```

How can I combine GARCH and copulas for fitting the model and creating a VaR curve?